# using ngmodel and formcontrol both in angular 7

Tags: angular7

Angular 7 says that you did not use ngmodel and formcontrol together, but when I use both in my app form, it work only with warning.
Is any one know the reason why is this happing in angular 7

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want to use both ngModel and formControlName together? In most of the cases formControlName should serve the purpose of two-way data binding.

Comment: I assume you want to use ngModel and formControlName together because you're trying to bind the value to something like a MobX object?